# Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Stream not writing to destination topic after join

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

This is my application that simply gets a reference to a KStream from customer topic (input binding) and another one from order topic (order binding). Then it creates a KTable from the customer topic and performs a join with the order KStream:

```
@Configuration
class ShippingKStreamConfiguration {


    @StreamListener
    @SendTo("output")
    fun process(@Input("input") input: KStream<Int, Customer>, @Input("order") order: KStream<Int, Order>): KStream<Int, OrderShipped> {

        val intSerde = Serdes.IntegerSerde()
        val customerSerde = JsonSerde<Customer>(Customer::class.java)
        val orderSerde = JsonSerde<Order>(Order::class.java)

        val stateStore: Materialized<Int, Customer, KeyValueStore<Bytes, ByteArray>> =
                Materialized.`as`<Int, Customer, KeyValueStore<Bytes, ByteArray>>("customer-store")
                        .withKeySerde(intSerde)
                        .withValueSerde(customerSerde)

        val customerTable: KTable<Int, Customer> = input.groupByKey(Serialized.with(intSerde, customerSerde))
                .reduce({ _, y -> y }, stateStore)

        return (order.selectKey { key, value -> value.customerId } as KStream<Int, Order>)
                .join(customerTable, { orderIt, customer ->
                    OrderShipped(orderIt.id)
                },
                        Joined.with(intSerde, orderSerde, customerSerde))

    }

}
```

Supposedly this should be writing to an output binding (`@SendTo("output")`), pointing at an ordershipment topic. However no messages are written to that topic.

**Processor config:**

```
interface ShippingKStreamProcessor {

    @Input("input")
    fun input(): KStream<Int, Customer>

    @Input("order")
    fun order(): KStream<String, Order>

    @Input("output")
    fun output(): KStream<String, OrderShipped>

}

**application.yml**

spring:
  application:
    name: spring-boot-shipping-service
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        streams:
          binder:
            configuration:
              default:
                key:
                  serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$IntegerSerde
                value:
                  serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
      bindings:
        input:
          destination: customer
          contentType: application/json
        order:
          destination: order
          contentType: application/json
        output:
          destination: ordershipments
          contentType: application/json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The processor was defined wrong, this is the good one using `@Output` instead of `@Input`:

```
interface ShippingKStreamProcessor {

    @Input("input")
    fun input(): KStream<Int, Customer>

    @Input("order")
    fun order(): KStream<String, Order>

    @Output("output")
    fun output(): KStream<String, OrderShipped>

}
```